# Unable to hit public AWS API gateway endpoints if a VPC Endpoint is created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am trying to set up a VPC endpoint in an existing VPC.
I am able to make calls to the private gateway endpoints from the lambda which is within the VPC.

Problem:
When I try to invoke a Regional API gateway endpoint, I am getting a 403.
Nat Gateway is setup. I am able to hit the internet via NAT gateway.

I need to call the private endpoint as well as regional endpoints from the lambdas within the VPC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VPC endpoint shadows your public API endpoints. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html):

> you cannot access public APIs from a VPC by using an API Gateway VPC endpoint with **private DNS enabled**

Thus, you can  disable [private DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/verify-domains.html) for the VPC endpoint. This way, you will have to explicitly use private VPC endpoint URL in your lambda.

Alternative way to access public API is [through](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html):

> Note that these DNS settings don't affect the ability to call these public APIs from the VPC if you're using an **edge-optimized custom domain** name to access the public API